# Java: convert HashMap values to Set<Integer>

Tags: java, hashmap, set

One more question about HashMap<> in Java:

I have the following

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myWordDict = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

After storing data into the variable `myWordDict`, I want to iterate through the HashMapValues, and add each value to a new Set variable?

When I try to do `Set<Integer> newVariable = myWordDict.entrySet()`, it seems the data type is incompatible.

**So my question is essentially:**

> how to convert HashMap values or entrySet() to Set ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the map value type?

Comment: Do you want all the key-value combinations as a set? Or do you only want the keys or values?

Comment: I wish to have only the values in the Set<Integer>. The value type is of Integer.

Comment: @TonyGW You say the value type is Integer, but in the above example the value type is actually Set<Integer>.

Comment: yes, the value is Set<Integer>. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Could you accept the answer that solved your problem or provide the solution you went with?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your declaration should be like below. It will convert your map values to `Collection`

```
  Collection<Set<Integer>> newVariable = myWordDict.values();
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work?! Firstly, you'll have to cast it and even if you do that, it'll throw a `ClassCastException`.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
Set<Integer> newVariable = mywordDict.keySet();
```

or

```
Set<Integer> newVariable = new HashSet<Integer>(myWordDict.values());
```

Answer (score 5):

[What does `entrySet` returns?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#entrySet%28%29)

```
public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()
```

> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. The set is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the set, and vice-versa.

If you want iterate over the `myWordDict` hash map then just

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Set<Integer>> entry : myWordDict.entrySet())
{
   Set<Integer> newVariable = entry.getValue();
}
```

**Related links**

- [Map.Entry#getValue()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue%28%29)

Comment: I am now using an iterator to iterate through the HashMap value:

Answer (score 4):

If you need all the values as a `Set` of `Integers` and not as a `Set` of `Set`, then you could do something like this

```
Set<Integer> newVariable = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (Set<Integer> set : myWordDict.values()) {
    newVariable.addAll(set);
}
```

Or if you want them as a `Set` of `Set`, you need to do something like this

```
Set<Set<Integer>> newVariable = new HashSet<Set<Integer>>();
newVariable.addAll(myWordDict.values());
```

Answer (score 3):

flatMap will help you:

```
myWordDict.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `myWordDict.values()`, not `myWordDict.entrySet()`. values is a set of the map's `values`, whereas `entrySet` is a set of its mappings (it is a set of java.util.map.Entry objects, each of which describes a key and a value).

Comment: values() is of Collections type, so there's also data incompatibility problem unless I do an ugly cast.

Comment: @TonyGW AFAIK there's no way around that, unless you want to construct the set manually by adding every value from the entry set.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<Integer,String>   map1 = new HashMap<Integer,String>();

map1.put(1, "Rakesh");
map1.put(2, "Amal");
map1.put(3, "Nithish");

Set<Entry<Integer,String>> set1 = map1.entrySet();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to add all values from the sets in the map your approach to do it is to use [addAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method:

```
Set<Integer> newVariable = new HashSet<Integer>();
for (Set<Integer> set : myWordDict.values()) {
    newVariable.addAll(set);
}
```

Comment: @TonyGW it runs accordingly to the number of entries in your `myWordDict` - if you have 10 entries, `for` loop will make 10 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

So, I came up with an iterator to iterate through the value Set

I have this data structure

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> myWordDict = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

I created

```
Iterator mapIterator = myWordDict.entrySet().iterator();
```

Then just use a while() loop to add individual value to a new Set variable. I am not sure this is the most efficient way, but it works for my needs.`